# Custom Mask Function does not work when inserting character in the middle Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a function:

```
function maskInput(input, location, delimiter, length) {
    //Get the delimiter positons
    var locs = location.split(',');

    //Iterate until all the delimiters are placed in the textbox
    for (var delimCount = 0; delimCount <= locs.length; delimCount++) {
        for (var inputCharCount = 0; inputCharCount <= input.length; inputCharCount++) {

            //Check for the actual position of the delimiter
            if (inputCharCount == locs[delimCount]) {

                //Confirm that the delimiter is not already present in that position
                if (input.substring(inputCharCount, inputCharCount + 1) != delimiter) {
                    input = input.substring(0, inputCharCount) + delimiter + input.substring(inputCharCount, input.length);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    input = input.length > length ? input.substring(0, length) : input;

    return input;
}
```

I use this in:

```
$(document).on('keypress paste drop blur', '#my_phone_number', function() {
    //remove any nondigit characters
    var myVal = $(this).val().toString().replace(/\D/g,'');
    $(this).val(myVal);


    var inVal   = maskInput(myVal, '3,7', '-', 12);

    $(this).val(inVal);
});
```

This works perfectly but when I try to remove a digit from the middle of string and then add it again it appends it to the end of string, does not stick to the current position.

Example:

```
 Entered String: '1234567890'
 After Mask Function Is Called: '123-456-7890'
 Number 5 removed and entered Number 8 instead of 5: '123-467-8908'
```

Note that it appended number **8** at the end of string.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `keyup` instead of `keypress`, since on `keypress` the value of input is not yet changed and you apply your filter prior to new value is posted to input. That is the reason why new character is appended.

```
$(document).on('keyup paste drop blur', '#my_phone_number', function() {
    ...
});
```

Example of working code here http://jsbin.com/upinux/1/edit